# Permission denied with nginx and nfs

Tags: nginx, nfs, nfs4

I have two RHEL 7 machines.

I have installed nginx and php-fpm and setup a nfs mount.  I can read/write to the nfs mount without issues and I have another application server (Apache Geronimo) that is able to read write to it.

When I installed nginx it setup a nginx user which I created on the NFS file server with the same uid and gid.

I am able to list out files on the nfs client mount using the nginx user.  However when I tried to serve up static html or dynamic php files using nginx from the nfs I get a permission error:

```
*5 stat() "/usr/depot/repository/test.php" failed (13: Permission denied)
*5 open() "/usr/depot/repository/test.html" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

In addition I created folder under /usr/depot/testing with the same permissions (just wasn't nfs) and that worked just fine.

Here is the mounting info on the client.

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/mnt/repository on /usr/depot/repository type nfs4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,local_lock=none,addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

I can't see anything wrong with this setup so I'm at a loss as to why nginx can't read the files from the nfs share.

**Update**

Ok I just disabled SELinux reboot and that fixed it. Now the question is how do I configure SELinux so that nginx can access the remote server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In RHEL 7, the same SELinux policies that apply to Apache also apply to nginx. So you can use the same booleans:

```
httpd_use_nfs                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use nfs
```

Set the correct boolean to allow the web server to use NFS.

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used SELinux before so looks like I need to start reading up on the default policies.

Answer (score 2):

As this is the first result on Google for this problem, I thought I'd add my solution.

In my case, SELinux was disabled, so that was not it. My problem was that php-fpm was running as apache. So on my CentOS 7 web servers (assuming you created an nginx user on the file server as per the OP) I change user and group to nginx in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf and restarted php-fpm.

Comment: This was the case for me using Amazon Linux in EC2.